# How to scrape data on a web site that is changing contents in active manner?

Tags: web-scraping, dataformat

I would like to grab satellite positions from the page(s) below, but I'm not sure if scraping is appropriate because the page appears to be updating itself every second using some internal code (it keeps updating after I disconnect from the internet). Background information can be found in my question at Space Stackexchange: A nicer way to download the positions of the Orbcomm-2 satellites.

I need a "**snapshot**" of four items simultaneously:

- UTC time
- latitude
- longitude
- altitude

Right now I use screen shots and manual typing. Since these values are being updated by the page - is conventional web-scraping going to work here? I found a "screen-scraping" tag, should I try to learn about that instead?

I'm looking for the simplest solution to get those four values, I wonder if I can just use urllib or urllib2 and avoid installing something new?

example page: http://www.satview.org/?sat_id=41186U I need to do 41179U through 41189U (the eleven Orbcomm-2 satellites that SpaceX just put in orbit)

Answer (score 0):

Those values are calculated with a little math using javascript. The calculations are detailed here: https://www.satview.org/track.js

So, I guess one option is to write that script (plus any dependencies) in the language of your choice and use  it to return your desired values.

There is one major function `track()` which takes arg `$modo` which can be one of two values - `tic` or `plot`.

There may be other source files (dependencies) referenced:

[image]

The easier way would probably be to use something which allows javascript to run e.g. automating a browser, and extracting the calculated values as they are generated.